# How can I use C++ STL containers in the implementation file of a C library?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, shared-libraries

Say I wish to use C++ STL containers in the implementation of a library that I want C programs to link to...

My example header is

```
/* mynums.h */
#ifndef MY_NUMS
#define MY_NUMS

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void append_num(int num);
void print_nums();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

And my example implementation file is

```
/* mynums.cpp */
#include "mynums.h"
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

vector<int> nums;

void append_num(int num)
{
    nums.push_back(num);
}

void print_nums()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", nums[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

My application looks like

```
/* app.c */
#include "mynums.h"

int main()
{
    append_num(1);
    append_num(2);
    append_num(3);
    print_nums();

    return 0;
}
```

And my commands to compile these are

```
# Compiles and runs
g++ -c -fpic -shared -std=c++0x -o libmynums.so mynums.cpp
g++ -L. -lmynums -o app app.c

# Library compiles, but the application fails
g++ -c -fpic -shared -std=c++0x -o libmynums.so mynums.cpp
gcc -L. -lmynums -o app app.c
```

The errors I get when I try the second set of compilation commands are those very long stl errors we're oh-so familiar with. One example is

```
./libmynums.so" In function 'void std:vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_emplace_back_aux<int const&>(int const &)':
mynums.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE19_M_emplace_back_auxIIRKiEEEvDpOT_[_ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE19_M_emplace_back_auxIIRKiEEEvDpOT_]+0x15d): undefined reference to '__cxa-begin_catch'
```

I want to be able to compile and link my example application code to the shared object library using gcc. Is this possible? If so, then what changes are necessary to my provided code / commands?

Comment: Names like `____MY_NUMS` are reserved in C and C++ for the implementation - you are not allowed to create them in your own code. And you can compile .c files with g++.

Comment: Note that an alternate fix, if you want a static library or just plain object files, would be to use `g++` for the final linking instead of `gcc`.

Comment: You need to add the `extern "C"` to the function definitions in your `mynums.cpp` file.

Comment: @Galik No you don't.  The compiler has already seen that in the function declaration in the header file.

Comment: @PaulSanders Really? I didn't realize that. I had just assumed the compiler would see them as different functions due to name mangling.

Comment: @Galik, No, it works.  Once the compiler has seen a function declared as `extern "C"` then it remembers that when it comes across the definition of that function, even if the definition is in a .cpp file (else OP different linker error).

Comment: @DietrichEpp I would have loved to call the fix at that, but this API needs to be used by C programmers. The implementation needed to be invisible, which means the programmers should not "know" the api was implemented using C++, which means they should be able to use gcc.

Comment: remove -c. -c is needed to create .o files. replace -fpic with -fPIC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you're not actually creating a shared library.  You're creating an object file and naming it as if it were a shared library.

The `-c` option to gcc/g++ means to perform the compilation stage only.  This results in `libmynums.so` being an object file.  This is why you're able to link to it via g++ but not gcc.

Remove the `-c` option when compiling `mynums.cpp` and you'll get a shared library.

Comment: That was the fix. Thanks a bunch!